Does a pop pop boat work with vacuum above the water?
(Given that there is an internal oxygen source then, of course.)
In other words:

Does the fluid pressure due to the boat's pipe(s) being underwater add to the water being pressed into the tube(s) in the second phase?

Or, on the other hand, does the fluid pressure applied to the front of the boat and the pipe(s) underneath cancel out the one that's applied at the back?


WP's Pop pop boat only mentions atmospheric [air] pressure in this process:

The momentum of the column of water in the exhaust tube keeps it moving outward, so that the pressure inside the boiler drops below atmospheric pressure [which causes the water to be pressed into the tube(s) in the second phase].

[Emphasis and comment by me.]

The phase diagram suggests that liquid water does not exist in vacuum. There will be some atmospheric pressure, probably maintained by water vapor, and things go back to the usual case. If you try to maintain liquid water in vacuum by constantly adding water to a low pressure environment, the water will boil and the boat would sink.

As a communicating vessel, the pressure from the depth of water also adds to the atmospheric pressure, but it depends on the height of the boiling chamber.

@MaYe Good point, the vaporazation! However, it was just to rule out atmospheric pressure vs. fluid pressure for this "thought experiment".

@MaYe The boiling chamber is not under fluid pressure at all of the pop pop boats I have seen since it's above the water level. Does that mean f. p. is not added in this case? And furthermore, has the height of the chamber above water level to be subtracted from the height of the air column to get the applied air pressure?

By way of example consider a pop pop boat with:
Exhaust outlet 3 metres below the lake level.
Boiler coil 1m above lake level.
Initially any water in the coil is vaporised and pushes any water out the coil and exhaust pipes. The water the exhaust is immersed in cools the metal tubes and reduces the pressure in the pipe system. To raise water from the exhaust level to the coil level, a water head of 4 metres is required. Since atmospheric pressure is approximately equal to 10 metres, there is no problem pushing the water back into the heating coil. With a vacuum above the lake, there is only a water head of 3m above the exhaust pipe outlet which is unable to push water 4m uphill, so the answer is the pop pop boat will not work with a vacuum above the lake, if the heating coil is above the lake water level.
Some finer details can be noted: The inrushing water may rise to slightly higher level than the surrounding water due to the momentum of the in-rushing water. The condensing steam may not have formed a perfect vacuum, so the incoming water might not rise to exactly the same level as the surround water.
However, if the boat has a deep hull and the heating coil is located in the bottom of the boat, below the lake surface, it could work with a vacuum above the lake, if the heating device does not need oxygen to work.

Two remarks: 1. Re "pushes any water out the coil and exhaust pipes" isn't necessarily so: https://youtu.be/3AXupc7oE-g?t=172, 2. Re"The water the exhaust is immersed in cools the metal tubes and reduces the pressure": The tubes aren't necessarily of metal (see video) and if always and only a filled part of them is underwater I think cooling them adds close to nothing to pressure reduction. I think the cooling will be largely due to the depressurization of the steam (and the bordering surface of steam/water column adds a bit).

@GeroldBroser Imagine the exhaust outlet is at a depth of 10 meters.  The hydraulic pressure at that depth is 1 bar plus an additional 1 bar due to the atmosphere above the water level. The steam pressure has to be 2 bar to push all the the water out. There will now be an equilibrium between the steam vapour pressure and the water pressure immediately outside the outlet. (Both 2 bar). How does the steam depressurise without cooling? It cannot continue to vent because the steam would have to be at a greater pressure than 2 bar.

That's just theoretical and out of scope of this use case. Pop pop boats don't have such deep-going tubes. The steam depressurizes because it presses the water out and due to the inertia of the moving water column it doesn't stop suddenly and exactly when pressure equilibrium is reached but goes a little further out.

@GeroldBroser I guess a possible mechanism when the exhaust tubes have low thermal conductivity is to imagine a bubble of steam just outside the outlet. This bubble is in direct contact with cold water and rapidly cools and collapses and water rushes in to fill the collapsing cavity. Due to momentum some of this in-rushing water continues into the the exhaust, cooling steam inside the tubes, drawing more water in and cooling more steam.

@GeroldBroser Yes, the inertia aspect of the ejecting steam makes sense. However the crux of this question is not about exactly how they work, but if they can work in a vacuum. I think I have addressed that aspect. The exact depth of the tubes is not important. They only have be below the surface to draw in water.

@GeroldBroser I think heat conducting exhaust tube with a larger contact area with the water would make for a more efficient propulsion system, but I will concede that cooling is not the only mechanism at play here and that momentum of the steam is an important aspect.
